# Immovable object

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry, literature

I have a long history from east to west,
to some I'm the worst and others the best.
With a core made of resin I dance and I flutter,
no one judges me when I speak with a stutter.

I may be an object of legend or myth,
at first you won't find me but maybe in fifth. 
For at any point, you summon power of three, 
And look to the wind, you may just find me.

My presence strengthens each link in the chain, 
certain times that you use me, it may be in vain. 
Storms when you're older and peace as a child, 
with us two together, adventures are wild.

A limited spectrum between ceiling and floor, 
Shot full of holes from twelve until four. 
In solving this riddle you're just out Of Time,
you should hear my voice as it is sublime.

It should be clear by now that I'm not a Paid Genius Poet,
"What am I, I ask?," by now you should know it.

(Edit) Rearranged stanzas and hints and got rid of spoilers `>!`

Part 3

Comment: "resincore" should be a synonym of "stoner metal"

Comment: If you're going to downvote please explain why. There have been a bunch of hard rhyme riddles posted. This is just one of the first parts and there is a definitive answer that clearly makes sense when you pay attention to what is said very closely.

Comment: I don't know why I got a notification about your comment but just FYI, I'm one of the three upvotes on this.

Comment: If you like the challenge of these wait til the last one. ;)

Comment: @question_asker Re [notification](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/28306/immovable-object#comment83998_28306): It's not necessarily directed at you - see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82134/micro-refinement-to-notifications-for-comments-of-others-posts).

Comment: @Lawrence No, I know it wasn't directed at me, and I figured the mechanism was something like that, I just wanted to clarify. But thank you for the link, it confirmed what I assumed.

Comment: Was this ever solved? I'm very curious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are

> An ocarina

I have a long history from east to west,
to some I'm the worst and others the best.

> [*"The ocarina belongs to a very old family of instruments, believed to date back over 12,000 years."*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ocarina)

With a core made of resin I dance and I flutter,
no one judges me when I speak with a stutter.

> They can be played legato or staccato. The ocarina has a *resonating* chamber (on which *resin* is a pun); being a wind instrument, it's a relative of the *flute* (hence: *flutter*)

I may be an object of legend or myth,
at first you won't find me but maybe in fifth.

> It's present in the fifth *[Legend of Zelda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Zelda)* game released, *The Ocarina of Time*, in which it was part of the game's lore.

For at any point, you summon power of three,
And look to the wind, you may just find me.

> OK, we're into video game territory for sure here. The power of three could be the Triforce. It also could have to do with the three stones you have to gather from the Forest, Fire, and Water temples before you get the Ocarina of Time. *Wind* has to do with the type of instrument it is.

My presence strengthens each link in the chain,
certain times that you use me, it may be in vain.

> Sometimes when you use the ocarina in the game, nothing happens. And "link" refers to, well, **Link**

Storms when you're older and peace as a child,
with us two together, adventures are wild.

> Adult Link saves areas from evil - prior to this, the areas are ravaged with fire and storms; afterward, they are calm, as they were when he was a child.  Also, the Song of Storms is a song that is taught only to Adult Link.

A limited spectrum between ceiling and floor,
Shot full of holes from twelve until four.

> OK, this is back to regular ocarinae: The ocarina doesn't allow for a very wide range of notes, and also: *"[v]ariations exist, but a typical ocarina is an enclosed space with **four to twelve finger holes** and a mouthpiece that projects from the body."* - *ibid.*

In solving this riddle you're just out Of Time,
you should hear my voice as it is sublime.

> The Ocarina **of Time**! Hooray! And "sublime voice" refers to the beautiful sound it makes.

It should be clear by now that I'm not a Paid Genius Poet,
"What am I, I ask?," by now you should know it.

> "Paid Genius Poet" is an anagram of [Giuseppe Donati, inventor of the ocarina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giuseppe_Donati)

Comment: @Z.Dailey hahaha holy crap, thank you, I'll add that to the answer. Funny thing is, I was sure it was a certain other wind instrument first, and then I started seeing the ... other ... connections.

Comment: Haha. I'm just glad someone got it. I had added a few stanzas. What did you originally think it was instrument-wise?

Comment: @Z.Dailey I was originally going with `pynevarg` or `bobr` (rot13ed as to not spoil it for anyone casually looking), and some of the hints fit, but not nearly as many as with the correct answer.

Comment: Yah. It had DEFINITELY been limited with all the hints to where only one answer fit.

Comment: Gunna take a stab at part 4? It's back to common knowledge. This one was a little niche.

Comment: @Z.Dailey Yeah, I've had that one up in a tab - it's pretty tough! I was sure the `ubengvb aryfba` answer was correct until I saw your comment.

Comment: yah. That was impressive. But it's a little simpler than that.

Comment: Great job on the solution, though I'm curious to see where the title ties in.

Comment: @feelinferrety When I figured out what the solution was, I was *sure* I knew what the title referred to... but then I did some research and realized I was super wrong. Unless it refers to the fact that there are no moving parts.

Comment: Teeheehee. Gunna have to wait and see? @feelinferrety

Comment: That makes me wonder whether it instead relates to the Meta puzzle, of which this is part 3, though according to OP on another answer, "the title may be part of the puzzle if you use it properly".  
  
Fun fact: etymology for the solution comes from the Latin for ROT13 `yvggyr tbbfr`. Edit: OP's comment that showed up before I posted mine makes me think even more that it's related to the meta.

Comment: @feelinferrety that's an interesting little fun fact. I didn't know that. :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a bit of a shot in the dark.

> Are you a dragon?

You're historically found in cultures throughout the world.

> In China you're considered lucky, but in the Dark Ages you were to be feared in tales of knights' heroics.

Resin is a flammable substance,

> Which ties into a dragon's flaming breath, as does the idea of no judgment when you spew red-hot flames at your enemies.

Obviously you're mythical, and the first/fifth…

> May be a reference to *The Elder Scrolls*, where dragons first appeared in the 5th game, *Skyrim*.

Comment: You have some really good thinking on this one. Feel free to run with similar ideas of solving the parts and see where else it takes you. Not the right answer tho. @brilliantlyInsane

Comment: @Z.Dailey even the title?

Comment: @manshu the title may be part of the puzzle if you use it properly. 2 parts have been solved. Feel free to interpret it as you please.

Answer (score 3):

Are you

> a violin?

I have a long history from east to west

> The violin has roots in the East and has been used in Western music since antiquity

to some I'm the worst and others the best.

> In capable hands, a violin can produce beautiful music. But the sounds produced by a beginning violinist can be pretty horrible.

With a core made of resin I dance and I flutter,

> Rosin is a "core" of resin that can be used to lubricate a violin bow

I may be an object of legend or myth

> Violins are often the subject of legends, like Nero's, which was supposedly played as Rome burned

at first you won't find me but maybe in fifth.

> Beethoven's *Fifth* heavily features violins.

no one judges me when I speak with a stutter.

> While violins can be played fluidly, they can also be played with a staccato.

For at any point, you summon power of three,
And look to the wind, you may just find me.

> Violins are often played in *trios*. There are *three* string instruments in Bach's *Air* on The G String, and Air on the G String is in the *Third* Orchestral Suite

Comment: Sorry. Not it. Great thought process though.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is not the intended answer (my achievement)...confirmed by OP

I think it is

> Fire

---

**Explanation**

---

I have a long history from east to west,
to some I'm the worst and others the best.

> Every culture had different thoughts on fire.

With a core made of resin I dance and I flutter,

> Resin ties into a dragon's flaming breath. (borrowed from @brilliantlyInsane's answer)

no one judges me when I speak with a stutter.

> You know, the popping sound.

I may be an object of legend or myth,

> Many mythical stories use it as power

at first you won't find me but maybe in fifth.

> It is one of the five elements of nature.

Comment: nice explanation, but not the right answer.  Trust me when you find the answer, everything fits absolutely perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Are you

> A Lamp

I have a long history from east to west,
to some I'm the worst and others the best.

> Long History, Yes. Worst for goons and criminals, best for the rest.

With a core made of resin I dance and I flutter,
no one judges me when I speak with a stutter.

> The fire inside the lamp dances and flutters.

I may be an object of legend or myth,
at first you won't find me but maybe in fifth.

> Legends like Arabian Nights had magical lamps.

For at any point, you summon power of three, 
And look to the wind, you may just find me.

> The three wishes of the genie in the lamp.

Storms when you're older and peace as a child, 
with us two together, adventures are wild.

> Maybe, another reference to the Genie in the Lamp.

Answer (score 1):

This riddle strongly reminds me of:

> **TARDIS**(Time and Relative Dimension In Space) from the series "Doctor Who"

I have a long history from east to west,
to some I'm the worst and others the best.

> The name says it all! It has a long history (It's a time machine!) and it has that history from east to west (It's also a transport device. It also travels through dimensions!). Its good for the universe and bad especially for the DALEKS.

With a core made of resin I dance and I flutter,
no one judges me when I speak with a stutter.

> I do not remember about the TARDIS core but the dance and flutter reference may be to how it operates in the show. No one judges the TARDIS!

I may be an object of legend or myth,
at first you won't find me but maybe in fifth.

> The TARDIS and Doctor Who is a kind of legendary series and both of them are known as legends or myth in the series as well. Not sure about the first and fifth reference.

For at any point, you summon power of three, 
And look to the wind, you may just find me.

> Power of three is an episode of Doctor Who and one can find TARDIS in the wind if it is really needed.

My presence strengthens each link in the chain, 
certain times that you use me, it may be in vain.

> In the show it is very creatively related to real life events hence the chain reference. Certain times it has gone in vain to use the TARDIS

Storms when you're older and peace as a child, 
with us two together, adventures are wild.

> There have been many wild adventures with the TARDIS, I'll provide the storm and peace explanation when I get it(Probably as the time passes.)

A limited spectrum between ceiling and floor, 
Shot full of holes from twelve until four.

> The TARDIS is small on the outside and bigger on the inside, hence the limited spectrum reference.

In solving this riddle you're just out Of Time,
you should hear my voice as it is sublime.

> The "out Of Time" phrase just makes me think about the TARDIS again. The sound it makes when it arrives is indeed sublime and provides hope to the people who hear it.

It should be clear by now that I'm not a Paid Genius Poet,
"What am I, I ask?," by now you should know it.

> You are not a paid genius poet and the biggest question on the series is "Doctor Who?"

Answer (score 1):

The answer:

> Fireworks

I have a long history from east to west,
to some I'm the worst and others the best.

> Fireworks comes from the east (asia) and has also been used in the west for many years. Some love it and some hate it.

With a core made of resin I dance and I flutter,
no one judges me when I speak with a stutter.

> fireworks may have had a core of resin, not sure on that. Fireworks makes a stuttering sound when launched, but we're nice people so we dont judge it :D

I may be an object of legend or myth,
at first you won't find me but maybe in fifth.

> Fireworks was used in China because of the myth that there are ghosts(or something supernatural like that). At the fifth of november there is a fireworks in london to celebrate guy fawkey night. (Remember remember the fifth of november ;))

For at any point, you summon power of three, 
And look to the wind, you may just find me.

> There are 3 classes of firework: daytime, nighttime and novelty fireworks. Some fireworks is shot in the sky, thats why you can find it there.

My presence strengthens each link in the chain, 
certain times that you use me, it may be in vain.

> Fireworks is used at newyear, and you might say it makes the link between the old and new year better/stronger. Sometimes fireworks doesnt go off, so its in vain.

Storms when you're older and peace as a child, 
with us two together, adventures are wild.

> When you're youngh you might only use sparklers, but when you're older you'll use fireworks that make alot of noise. Playing with fireworks can get wild.

A limited spectrum between ceiling and floor, 
Shot full of holes from twelve until four.

> You can only shoot fireworks between 12 and 4 at night. This is a limited timespan. (may also mean that it only goes a certain height up in the air)

In solving this riddle you're just out Of Time,
you should hear my voice as it is sublime.

> I toke too long in writing this stuff down, now the fireworks went off and i hear the bang.

It should be clear by now that I'm not a Paid Genius Poet,
"What am I, I ask?," by now you should know it.

> You are fireworks!!

Answer (score 1):

I do have some hole left, maybe someone can improve it

> you are the Levante , wich is a wind

I have a long history from east to west

> Blow from east to west

to some I'm the worst and others the best

> The winds are moist before the Strait of Gibraltar but dry after, carrying bad and good weather respectively

With a core made of resin I dance and I flutter

> don't know about the resin, but the "dance and flutter" stick with the idea

no one judges me when I speak with a stutter.

> it can produce winds of 20-40 kt (10-20 m/s), which, if i remeber corectly, is not that much for a wind

I may be an object of legend or myth,

> I have done some search and it's actually linked to some legend

at first you won't find me but maybe in fifth. 
For at any point, you summon power of three,

> i have no clue for this

And look to the wind, you may just find me.

> quite literally!

My presence strengthens each link in the chain, 
certain times that you use me, it may be in vain.

> maybe linked to sailing ?

Storms when you're older and peace as a child,

> yet again terms linked to winds

with us two together, adventures are wild.

> again linked to sailing and adventuring

A limited spectrum between ceiling and floor, 
Shot full of holes from twelve until four. 
In solving this riddle you're just out Of Time,
you should hear my voice as it is sublime.

> once again i have no clue here

Answer (score 0):

It feels a little like fitting the clues to the solution, rather than the other way around, but it could be:

> **Resistance** (which fits the title, "immovable object")

*I have a long history from east to west, / to some I'm the worst and others the best.*

> Resistances (as in, an uprisings against incumbent governments) are common throughout history, and are seen as the best by supporters, and as a terrorist act by others.

*With a core made of resin I dance and I flutter, / no one judges me when I speak with a stutter.*

> Word play on RESIn i dANCE ==> RESIstANCE ??

*I may be an object of legend or myth,*

> Plenty of legendary uprisings in history...

*at first you won't find me but maybe in fifth.*

> A reference to the US fifth amendment (right to remain silent), which could be seen as a form of resistance.

*It should be clear by now that I'm not a Paid Genius Poet, / "What am I, I ask?," by now you should know it.*

> Paid Genius Poet's capitalisation, PGP, could reference [Pretty Good Privacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) (encryption tool that could be used by members of a resistance) or "[multidrug resistance protein 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-glycoprotein)"...

*For at any point, you summon power of three, / And look to the wind, you may just find me.*

> Electrical resistors can be made by winding wire around another material ("look to the wind"), and on a resistor, there are coloured bands, where the third indicates the decimal multiplier ("three", "point", "power").

*My presence strengthens each link in the chain,*

> Resist against weakness?

*certain times that you use me, it may be in vain.*

> Resistance is futile

*Storms when you're older and peace as a child, / with us two together, adventures are wild.*

> Adults weather the storm, while kids resist peace & quiet?

Comment: Alright. I'll give another hint since this is one of the first parts. Might have to think a little nerdy on this one.

Comment: @Z.Dailey resistor power factors and PGP aren't nerdy enough? :)

Comment: Nope. ;). Those are scientific.

Comment: Seriously. Once someone gets it everyone is gunna be thinking "how didn't I get that" I've given a lot of really good clues.

Comment: you think it needs another stanza? I came up with a good one. I'm afraid it'll make it too easy tho. @Alconja

Comment: @Z.Dailey - hard to say... Maybe... If it's something general, then I'm not getting it (though me not getting it is by no means the definitive measure of difficulty). If it's something that's more niche/trivia (eg. by your comment of it being "nerdy", perhaps it's a specific character from a book/movie), then I may just never get it no matter how many clues if I'm not aware of the "thing".

Comment: This is the only one out of the 5 parts that's not necessarily known by everyone. But it is very common people would know it. Added another stanza anyway. @Alconja